# In app purchase not fully working

Tags: android

I just wrote a test application to test in app purchases, it's just a test application where you have to press a button and you purchase a "premium" membership that will make that button invisible (this is just a test app)

So after my friend pressed the button he got the payment screen, he paid, but when he got back to the app the button was still there

This is how i start the purchase

```
    // User clicked the "Upgrade to Premium" button.
    public void onUpgradeAppButtonClicked(View arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Upgrade button clicked; launching purchase flow for upgrade.");
   //     setWaitScreen(true);
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST,   mPurchaseFinishedListener);
    }
```

and when the purchase is finished

```
// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Oh noes!
         //   complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
         //   setWaitScreen(false);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed to purchase", duration).show();
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
            // bought the premium upgrade!
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is premium upgrade. Congratulating user.");
          //  alert("Thank you for upgrading to premium!");
            mIsPremium = true;

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You are now premium", duration).show();
            Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test);
            test.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          //  updateUi();
         //   setWaitScreen(false);
        }
    }
};
```

The code was taken from the sample app that was provided by google,i removed the parts i didn't need, maybe i removed something that was needed?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you must also copy the `onActivityResult` method from the example activity into your activity. When you have done this, it should work.